# Merge multiple CSVs with the similar filename

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge, data-cleaning

I have a large number of CSVs in a directory (1000+) that contain different data. Several CSVs have more/fewer columns than others and I want to be able to merge each CSV where the columns are the same. Fortunately, there is a string in each CSV filename that helps signifies which "group" it belongs too.

Consider the 3 examples:

```
CSV1 named: **Report3443_GMA_45_20210516_111358.csv**
Contains:
| Date       | ID     | Amount  |
| ---------- | ------ | ------- |
| 01/05/2021 | GMA_45 | 1565.43 |
| 02/05/2021 | GMA_45 | 58963.9 |
| 05/05/2021 | GMA_45 | 962.27  |

CSV2 named: **Report7853_ATH_16_20210516_095745.csv**
Contains:
| Date       | ID     | Amount  | Subgroup |
| ---------- | ------ | ------- | -------- |
| 03/05/2021 | ATH_16 | 6345.01 | 861312   |
| 04/05/2021 | ATH_16 | 7824.69 | 861312   |
| 09/05/2021 | ATH_16 | 962.27  | 846131   |

CSV3 named: **Report45896_GMA_45_20210516_143825.csv**
Contains:
| Date       | ID     | Amount  |
| ---------- | ------ | ------- |
| 11/05/2021 | GMA_45 | 9915.12 |
| 14/05/2021 | GMA_45 | 66452.05|
| 15/05/2021 | GMA_45 | 4893.85 |
```

As you can see CSV1 & CSV3 contain the same filename string (GMA_45) and they have the same number of columns. I'd want a merged version of these CSVs, along with any other iterations where the string in the filename is the same.

I used the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817769/merging-csvs-with-similar-name-python/33818093#33818093) to get me started along with some changes. The code works fine, although the output CSV writes a blank line between each row, and the header is duplicated each time a matching CSV is appended. How can I remove the blank lines and delete any duplicate header entires (apart from the main header)? I'd also like to remove any duplicate rows.

Here is my code:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas

def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):
    with open('Concat_{}.csv'.format(key), 'w+t') as outfile:
        for filename in filelist:
            df = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)
            df.to_csv(outfile, index=False, header=None)

def find_filesets(path="."):
    csv_files = {}
    for name in glob.glob("{}/*_*.csv".format(path)):
        key = '_'.join(name.split('_')[1:-2])
        csv_files.setdefault(key, []).append(name)

    for key,filelist in csv_files.items(): 
        print(key, filelist)
        create_merged_csv(key, filelist)

TEST_DIR_NAME="C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\Python\\MergeFiles\\Input"
os.chdir("MergeFiles")
find_filesets(TEST_DIR_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code, Please check it

```
import glob
import os
import pandas

def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):
    outfile = 'Concat_{}.csv'.format(key)
    l = []
    for filename in filelist:
        df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
        l.append(df)
    pd.concat(l).to_csv(outfile, index=False)

def find_filesets(path="."):
    csv_files = {}
    for name in glob.glob("{}/*_*.csv".format(path)):
        key = '_'.join(name.split('_')[1:-2])
        csv_files.setdefault(key, []).append(name)

    for key,filelist in csv_files.items(): 
        print(key, filelist)
        create_merged_csv(key, filelist)

TEST_DIR_NAME="C:\\Users\\ME\\Desktop\\Python\\MergeFiles\\Input"
os.chdir("MergeFiles")
find_filesets(TEST_DIR_NAME)
```

This might help